# How to save custom form data in wp_options table

Tags: plugin-options

I have some data that I want stored in the wp_option table.

I know the code is not right but I want to store data in this way:

```php
global $wpdb;

if (isset($_POST['add_estimated_satisfaction'])) {
    // run validation if you're not doing it in js
    $option_name = $confused_about_treatment_editor;
    $option_name = $estimated_price_editor;
    $option_name = $satisfaction_guarantee_editor;

    $option_value = isset($_POST['confused_about_treatment']) ? $_POST['confused_about_treatment'] : '';
    $option_value = isset($_POST['estimated_price']) ? $_POST['estimated_price'] : '';
    $option_value = isset($_POST['satisfaction_guarantee']) ? $_POST['satisfaction_guarantee'] : '';


    $status = $wpdb->insert('www_options', array(
        'option_name'  => $option_name,
        'option_value' => $option_value,

    ));

    if ($status == false) {
        echo $msg_fail;
    } else {
        echo $msg_success_save;
    };
    go_back();
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <table width="95%">
        <tr>
            <td width="10%">Confused about our treatment</td>
            <td width="90%">
                <?php
                $confused_about_treatment_content  = '';
                $confused_about_treatment_editor   = "confused_about_treatment";
                $confused_about_treatment_settings = array(
                    'textarea_name' => $confused_about_treatment_editor,
                    'textarea_rows' => 15,
                    'media_buttons' => false,
                    'teeny'         => false,
                    'tinymce'       => true,
                    'quicktags'     => false,
                );
                ?>
                <textarea style="display:none" name="<?php $confused_about_treatment_editor ?>" id="<?php $confused_about_treatment_editor ?>" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $confused_about_treatment_content ?></textarea>
                <?php wp_editor($confused_about_treatment_content, $confused_about_treatment_editor,
                    $confused_about_treatment_settings); ?>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="10%">Tooltip Estimated Price</td>
            <td width="90%">
                <?php
                $estimated_price_content  = '';
                $estimated_price_editor   = "estimated_price";
                $estimated_price_settings = array(
                    'textarea_name' => $estimated_price_editor,
                    'textarea_rows' => 5,
                    'media_buttons' => false,
                    'teeny'         => false,
                    'tinymce'       => false,
                    'quicktags'     => false,
                );
                ?>
                <textarea style="display:none" name="<?php $estimated_price_editor ?>" id="<?php $estimated_price_editor ?>" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $estimated_price_content ?></textarea>
                <?php wp_editor($estimated_price_content, $estimated_price_editor, $estimated_price_settings); ?>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="10%">Tooltip Satisfaction Guarantee</td>
            <td width="90%">
                <?php
                $satisfaction_guarantee_content  = '';
                $satisfaction_guarantee_editor   = "satisfaction_guarantee";
                $satisfaction_guarantee_settings = array(
                    'textarea_name' => $satisfaction_guarantee_editor,
                    'textarea_rows' => 5,
                    'media_buttons' => false,
                    'teeny'         => false,
                    'tinymce'       => false,
                    'quicktags'     => false,
                );
                ?>
                <textarea style="display:none" name="<?php $satisfaction_guarantee_editor ?>" id="<?php $satisfaction_guarantee_editor ?>" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $satisfaction_guarantee_content ?></textarea>
                <?php wp_editor($satisfaction_guarantee_content, $satisfaction_guarantee_editor,
                    $satisfaction_guarantee_settings); ?>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="add_estimated_satisfaction" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Wordpress has a built in function for inserting data into options, see [add_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/) for more information

Comment: @Buttered_Toast  thx . Can you edit my question and tell me the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Buttered_Toast's solutions is what you are looking for, if you were in a position to use it.

There are a bunch of problems with your code.

1. Variables `$confused_about_treatment_editor`, `$estimated_price_editor`, and `$satisfaction_guarantee_editor` are never instantiated.
2. The values of `$option_name` and `$option_value`are changed three times, but only the last value is ever used.
3. There is no closing PHP tag between your code and your form.

I'm not sure if you intend to call `go_back()` every time, but it is called every time.

I would recommend using [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) for form values that will be changed during the live of the site. For values that you don't want mutated you should use [`add_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/).

You could try removing everything between your `// run validation comment`, and `$status` variable instantiation with this...

```php
$status = update_option('form_values', [
    'confused_about_treatment' => isset( $_POST['confused_about_treatment'] ) ? $_POST['confused_about_treatment'] : '',
    'estimated_price' => isset( $_POST['estimated_price'] ) ? $_POST['estimated_price'] : '',
    'satisfaction_guarantee' => isset( $_POST['satisfaction_guarantee'] ) ? $_POST['satisfaction_guarantee'] : '',
]);
```

Comment: thx sir, i try but nothing happened Can you please tell me how it will be

Comment: See updated answer